# Does a *.example.com for a content security policy header also match example.com?

Tags: javascript, html, security, content-security-policy

Say I have this header set on `mywebsite.com`:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src self https://*.example.com
```

I know it will allow `https://foo.example.com` and `https://bar.example.com`, but will it allow `https://example.com` alone?

Looking at [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/)....

> Hosts such as example.com (which matches any resource on the host, regardless of scheme) or *.example.com (**which matches any resource on the host *or* any of its subdomains** (and any of its subdomains' subdomains, and so on))

...it seems as it should allow plain `https://example.com`. However, I've found several different sites ([site 1](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/), [site 2](http://qnimate.com/content-security-policy-in-nutshell/), [site 3](https://scotthelme.co.uk/content-security-policy-an-introduction/), [site 4](https://www.sitepoint.com/improving-web-security-with-the-content-security-policy/)) that **all** say that `https://example.com` isn't included. Which is it?

Comment: I may be a bit pedantic, but `example.com` is a ***domain***, while `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` are ***hosts***.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`*.example.com` for a CSP header doesn’t also match `example.com`, [per the current CSP spec](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#source-expression).

That text cited from the (old) CSP spec is wrong ([now fixed](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/pull/251/commits/da0f902e8bab21701fc4c8d0fa57a849af5dec4e)). The other sources cited are right.

---

But that https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#source-expression section cited, which defines what a CSP *source expression* is, isn’t actually stating the relevant normative requirements.

Instead the section of the CSP spec that does actually normatively define the relevant requirements is the [*Does url match expression in origin with redirect count*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#match-url-to-source-expression) algorithm, in a substep at https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#ref-for-grammardef-host-part-2 which reads:

> 3. If the first character of *expression*’s host-part is an U+002A ASTERISK character (`*`):
> 4. Let *remaining* be the result of removing the leading "`*`" from *expression*.
> 5. If *remaining* (including the leading U+002E FULL STOP character (`.`)) is not an ASCII case-insensitive match for the rightmost
>    characters of `url`’s host, then return "*Does Not Match*".

The *including the leading U+002E FULL STOP character (`.`)* part of the requirement indicates the *remaining* part after the asterisk is removed includes the leading full stop, and so the rightmost characters of `url`’s host must also start with a dot in order to match that.

In other words, if you start with `*.example.com` and walk through that part of the algorithm, you start by removing the `*` to get `.example.com` as the *remaining* part, and then you match the rightmost characters of `url`'s host against that, including the leading full stop.

So `https://foo.example.com`  matches, because the rightmost characters of its host part match `.example.com`, but `https://example.com` doesn’t match, because the rightmost characters of its host part don’t match `.example.com` (because it lacks the included full stop).

---

**2017-10-13 update**

A while back [I reported the problem](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/241) with the CSP spec and it’s [now been fixed](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/pull/251/commits/da0f902e8bab21701fc4c8d0fa57a849af5dec4e).

The [relevant part of the CSP spec](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#source-expression) now reads:

> Hosts such as `example.com` (which matches any resource on the host, regardless of scheme) or `*.example.com` (which matches any resource on the host’s subdomains (and any of its subdomains' subdomains, and so on))

Notice that the part which had read *“matches any resource on the host or any of its subdomains”* now just reads *“matches any resource on the host’s subdomains”*.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) you should include `'self'` as well as `*.example.com` in the CSP header if you want to include the base domain.

Comment: I should've made it clear that `example.com` is NOT my website. So `self` would allow `mydomain.com`, if I am understanding everything correctly. I updated my question to clarify.

Comment: Ah, alright. In that case I'd still stick with Mozilla's/w3 spec where *.example.com includes both a foreign websites' domain and subdomains.