# Content Security Policy and domain wildcards

Tags: content-security-policy

I want to allow external sites to embed iframes from my site.
I have setup Content Security Policy using frame-ancestors (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors).

Sites that need to be allowed are of format:

- example.com
- subdomain1.example.com
- subdomain2.example.com

Is it enough to set iframe-ancestors using wildcard:

```
frame-ancestors *.example.com
```

Or do I need to explitly list the example.com too:

```
frame-ancestors *.example.com example.com
```

Spec says: `http://*.example.com: Matches all attempts to load from any subdomain of example.com using the http: URL scheme.`
I'm not sure is example.com considered as such subdomain too in this context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a \*.example.com for a content security policy header also match example.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850590/does-a-example-com-for-a-content-security-policy-header-also-match-example-com)

Comment: To match `example.com`, you need to explicitly list it as you show in `frame-ancestors *.example.com example.com`. It won’t be matched if you instead just do `frame-ancestors *.example.com`