# Content Security policy setting in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, cross-domain, content-security-policy

I have an HTML and I want to open another iframe inside this and test for Content security policy.
My domain is **abc.def.com**.

If I am adding  ***.def.com** or **abc.def.com** or ***.com**, in the frame-ancestors it is allowing me to open the iframe which is expected behaviour.
However, if I add ***.abc.def.com** this is not getting allowed. What can be the reasons?

Comment: The `*.domain.com` host-source allows the subdomains only and [does not allow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#match-hosts) `domain.com` itself.

Comment: See also [Does a \*.example.com for a content security policy header also match example.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850590/does-a-example-com-for-a-content-security-policy-header-also-match-example-com)